# Match jquery finding

Tags: javascript

Can someone give me some explanation for this code:

```
.match(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig)[0];
```

I know it is for finding word next to # but I want to search for first word typed so I want to know how to change it ....

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F(%5E%7C%5Cs)(%23%5Ba-z%5Cd-%5D%2B)%2Fig

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just ordinary Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)